# How to make extension that shows in alert last element from list?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to make extension to chrome that shows last element from unordered list on csgopolygon.com , but i can't find which function does it.

```
<ul class="balls">   
          <li class="ball" data-rollid="3928081"><span class="red">2</span></li><li class="ball" data-rollid="3928082"><span class="red">5</span></li></ul>
```

manifest

```
{
  "name": "popup ",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "test",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body style="width: 300px">
  <a href="https://csgopolygon.com" target="_blank">this page</a>  
    <button id="clickme">click me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function popup() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'alert.js'
  }); 
}

document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', popup);
```

alert.js

```
var x = document.getElementById("balls").lastElementChild.innerHTML;
alert(x)
```

background.js

```
//empty
```

Comment: You haven't added what you have tried so far..

Comment: can you add your manifest file?

Comment: @souravsatyam you're right, it ain't much but it's honest work... I literally started lerning js yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Getting the last element of unorderlist using vanilla javascript.

```js
const ulList = document.getElementById("ul-le");
var nodes = Array.from( ulList.children );
console.log(nodes[nodes.length - 1]);
```

```html
<ul id="ul-le">
    <li class="ball" data-rollid="3928081">
      <span class="red">2</span>
      </li>
      <li class="ball" data-rollid="3928082">
        <span class="red">5</span>
       </li>
</ul>
```